# Jquery Toggle and Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create something in which when a user clicks on a picture it would display a set of info and when they click the picture again it would disappear and also if they were to click on a different image when one is already displayed, it would hide that images info and display the info for the recently clicked picture. I'm really new to JQuery and JS so I have problems thinking outside the box haha.

I have the display down, easily done with the .toggleClass(); but I don't know how to do the rest. It's exactly like a simple hover over but with clicks. Also only the first 2 work, since I'm trying to figure out how it works.

Thanks, much love. :)

```js
$(function () {
  $('.read').click(function() {
    $('.showread').toggleClass('pshow');
});

$('.sew').click(function() {
 $('.showsew').toggleClass('pshow');
 });
});
```

```css
.aboutmewrapper {
background: #2F3347;
height: 100vh;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}

.imagewrap {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.imagesec {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 0 30px;
flex-direction: column;
}

.imagesec i {
color: #ececec;
font-size: 100px;
}

.showread {
color: #ececec;
opacity: 0;
transition: 0.5s all ease;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);  
}

.showsew {
color: #ececec;
opacity: 0;
transition: 0.5s all ease;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);  
}

.psections {
position: relative;
bottom: 20%;
font-size: 25px;
}

.showread:before, .showsew:before {
content: '';
width: 5px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: #FE715D;
position: absolute;
left: -15px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.pshow {
opacity: 1;
}

.phide {
opacity: 0;
}

.imagesec img {
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
>
<div class="aboutmewrapper">

<div class="imagewrap">
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img class="read" src="https://i.imgur.com/3cgLq19.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img class="sew" src="https://i.imgur.com/jnwU44r.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MoV3QpE.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>        
    </div>
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yyC2Hjf.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>        
    </div>
</div>

<div class="psections">
    <p class="showread">Reading makes you smarter. That's why I read.</p>  
    <p class="showsew">Believe it or not I sew.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you're current intentions to have the images and messages separated like that?

Comment: @Taplar its not currently responsive, but the images are displayed on a row and the text that pops up should be below them, aligned center, on top of each other

Comment: @Taplar Yes, an example would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to dummy a message for image3, but hopefully you get the idea.

```js
$(function(){
  //put a delegate listener on the wrapper for all image clicks
  $('.imagewrap').on('click', 'img', function(e){
    //reference the image in a jquery object
    var $img = $(e.target);
    //get all the messages
    var $messages = $('.psections p');
    //construct the class of the message you want to show
    var messageClass = '.'+ $img.data('message');
    
    //hide any message other than the one we want
    $messages.not(messageClass).removeClass('pshow');
    
    //get the message we should change, and toggle the class, so if it already has it, it will be removed
    $messages.filter(messageClass).toggleClass('pshow');
  });
});
```

```css
.aboutmewrapper {
background: #2F3347;
height: 100vh;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}

.imagewrap {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.imagesec {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 0 30px;
flex-direction: column;
}

.imagesec i {
color: #ececec;
font-size: 100px;
}

.showread {
color: #ececec;
opacity: 0;
transition: 0.5s all ease;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);  
}

.showsew {
color: #ececec;
opacity: 0;
transition: 0.5s all ease;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);  
}

.psections {
position: relative;
bottom: 20%;
font-size: 25px;
}

.showread:before, .showsew:before {
content: '';
width: 5px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: #FE715D;
position: absolute;
left: -15px;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.pshow {
opacity: 1;
}

.phide {
opacity: 0;
}

.imagesec img {
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
>
<div class="aboutmewrapper">

<div class="imagewrap">
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img class="read" data-message="image1" src="https://i.imgur.com/3cgLq19.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img class="sew" data-message="image2" src="https://i.imgur.com/jnwU44r.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img data-message="image3" src="https://i.imgur.com/MoV3QpE.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>        
    </div>
    <div class="imagesec">
        <img data-message="image4" src="https://i.imgur.com/yyC2Hjf.png" alt="">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>        
    </div>
</div>

<div class="psections">
    <p class="showread image1">Reading makes you smarter. That's why I read.</p>  
    <p class="showsew image2">Believe it or not I sew.</p>
    <p class="showsew image3">Believe it or not I lift weights.</p>
    <p class="showsew image4">Believe it or not I sew.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do!
2 questions: Is there a way without use data-message?
How would you make it so when you click on the same image, the text goes away?

Comment: I'd advise the use of something like the data-message, or maybe just make the class on the image and p the same, but a data-* field is easier to grab.  As far as being able to double click to make it go away, I missed that.  Give me a sec to edit the answer.

Comment: @GabrielPozo there we go